# BigDecimal from Double incorrect value?

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal

I am trying to make a BigDecimal from a string. Don't ask me why, I just need it! This is my code:

```
Double theDouble = new Double(".3");
System.out.println("The Double: " + theDouble.toString());
BigDecimal theBigDecimal = new BigDecimal(theDouble);
System.out.println("The Big: " + theBigDecimal.toString());
```

This is the output I get?

```
The Double: 0.3
The Big: 0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you create a double, the value 0.3 cannot be represented exactly.   You can create a BigDecimal from a string without the intermediate double, as in

```
new BigDecimal("0.3")
```

A floating point number is represented as a binary fraction and an exponent.  Therefore there are some number that cannot be represented  exactly.   There is an analogous problem in base 10 with numbers like 1/3, which is 0.333333333.....  Any decimal representation of 1/3 is inexact.  This happens to a DIFFERENT set of fractions in binary, and 0.3 is one of the set that is inexact in binary.

Comment: Why cant it be represented exactly as a double?

Comment: @Diego: This is, if not the most common question on SO, at least in the top five.  It takes a little time to understand, though. Read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Heck, you supplied the canonical answer to this question and is the duplicate you should have used to close the recent [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45663315/multiply-two-numbers-precisely-in-java).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've lost track of which "canonical" answers I've written.  This was almost 7 years ago :-)

Comment: Well it has well stood the test of time.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use [`MathContext.DECIMAL32`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html#DECIMAL32) which guarantees 7 digit precision (which is good enough in our case):

```
Double theDouble = new Double(".3");
System.out.println("The Double: " + theDouble.toString());
BigDecimal theBigDecimal = new BigDecimal(theDouble, MathContext.DECIMAL32);  // <-- here
System.out.println("The Big: " + theBigDecimal.toString());
```

**OUTPUT**

```
The Double: 0.3
The Big: 0.3000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `new Double(".3")` can't be represented exactly, the nearest value is `0x1.3333333333333P-2` or `.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875`, what would be need to is this:

```
Double theDouble = new Double(".3");
System.out.println("The Double: " + theDouble.toString());
BigDecimal theBigDecimal = new 
BigDecimal(theDouble).setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING);  // <-- here
System.out.println("The Big: " + theBigDecimal.toString());
```

This will print:

```
The Double: 0.3
The Big: 0.30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a big decimal a specified precision. e.g. append to your example:

```
Double theDouble = new Double(".3");
theBigDecimal = new BigDecimal(theDouble, new MathContext(2));
System.out.println("The Big: " + theBigDecimal.toString());
```

This will print out "0.30"

Comment: Thanks, but I dont always know that the precision would be. The string I am actually reading from a file.