# Surprising behaviour of BigDecimal when rounding with HALF_UP rounding mode

Tags: java, math, rounding, bigdecimal

I am creating a BigDecimal from a double value of 0.495, and printing it to two decimal digits with `HALF_UP` rounding mode. Here's the code:

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(0.495);
d = d.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
System.out.println(d.toPlainString());
```

I am expecting to see 0.50 as the result, but I am seeing 0.49 instead. `ROUND_HALF_UP` should round up if the discarded fraction is `>= .5.`

So why am I seeing this behaviour?

Comment: Bear in mind that if you start with a double `0.495`, you're already approximating, before the `BigDecimal` is even instantiated. What if you start with `"0.495"` instead?

Comment: When you use 0.495 you actually get 0.49499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693014/bigdecimal-from-double-incorrect-value

Comment: In other words: if you want to initialize a BigDecimal to an exact decimal value, **NEVER** use a double. Use a string, if you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write

```
new BigDecimal(0.495)
```

you are passing a `double` value to the `BigDecimal` constructor. Double values are approximations. In this case, your `BigDecimal` instance has a value a little under `0.495` from the point it is instantiated.

If you pass a string instead of a double, the `BigDecimal` will represent the exact value indicated by the string.

So use

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("0.495");
```